# Manage I/O and POI exception in a customReaderItem

Tags: spring, apache-poi, spring-batch

I'm using a `customReader` that implements `ItemReader`. My reader take information from xls and treat it row by row. My constructor take `Iterator` value that will be read on each `read()` iteration. I'm trying to find a suitable way to manage exception. I look through `SkipListener` and `ReaderListener` `onReadError`. But Ican't use either because my exception will be thrown in the constructor before attempting `read()` method.

Is there any way to do that in order to allow me to manage properly action1/2/3 respectively to exceptions ?

```
@Component
public class CustomReaderFile implements ItemReader<Row> {

    private final Iterator<Row> data;
    private static final String FILE_NAME = "";

    public CustomReaderFile() throws Exception {
        this.data = iteratorFromXls();
    }

    @Override
    public Row read() throws Exception {
        if (this.data.hasNext()) {
            return this.data.next();
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }


    public static Iterator<Row> iteratorFromXls() throws Exception {
        Iterator<Row> iterator = null;
        try {
            FileInputStream excelFile = new FileInputStream(new File(FILE_NAME));
            Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(excelFile);
            Sheet dataTypeSheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
            iterator = dataTypeSheet.iterator();  
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        //action1
        } catch (IOException e) {
        //action2
        } catch (NotOfficeXmlFileException e){
        //action3
        }

        return iterator;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually the reader's initialization code. The reading part is nothing more than calling `.next` on the iterator.

So I would make the reader implement `ItemStreamReader` and put the initialization code in the `open` method, in which you can throw an exception to signal to Spring Batch that the reader's initialization has failed.